# integral $\int_A {e^{2(x+y)} (1+e^y)} dx dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_A {e^{2(x+y)} (1+e^y)} \, dx \, dy$$

I've to calculate this integral on a domain $$A=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : \quad e^y-2\le x \le e^2, \quad -y-1 \le x \le -y+1\}.$$

Is $A$ a $x$-simple or $y$-simple domain?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better do a picture of this domain; you have this[image]

Take the intersection of the curve in green ($e^y-2=x$) with the curves in red and blue ($-y-1=x$ and $-y+1=x$ repectively). Let those points be $x_1$ and $x_2$: you see you can partition the domain into 2 subdomains[image]

namely $A_1$ the domain of the left and $A_2$ the domain of the right. Then you have

\begin{equation*}
A_1 = \{(x,y) | x_1 \leq x \leq x_2 , -x-1 \leq y \leq \ln(2+x) \}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
A_2 = \{(x,y) | x_2 \leq x \leq e^2 , -x-1 \leq y \leq -x+1
\end{equation*}

with those domains you can now compute easily the integral:
\begin{equation*}
\int_A = \int_{A_1} + \int_{A_2}
\end{equation*}